# Приведите пример процедуры вывода строки на экран

Tags: ассемблер

Приведите пожалуйста пример процедуры вывода строки на экран с помощью DOS, желательно с комментариями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

полный интернет же этого "добра".
Вкратце

1. подготовка регистров:

   - `ds:dx` - сюда записываем адрес строки
   - `ah` - код операции `09h` (вывод строки на экран.)
2. вызов прерывания `21h`

masm

```
model small
.stack   100h
.data
message1 db   'Это моя строка’,’$'    
.code    
start:
     mov  ax,@data
     mov  ds,ax
     mov  dx,offset message1
     ; На входе - ds:dx  = адрес строки с символом $ на конце 
     mov  ah,09h
     int  21h    
end  start
```